# .htaccess file on the localhost

Tags: apache, .htaccess, localhost

I am trying rewrite my url by `.htaccess` file. I tried to find out solution before I ask but nothing to seem work. Could you please help out? Thank you.

Here is my .htaccess file (In the root folders):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^film/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /html/movie/film.php?film=$1&genreID=$2 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

I did set these lines (in etc/apache2/sites-available/ 000-default.conf):

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory "/var/www/html/movie">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

I am using Linux mate Apache 2.4.7 and in `error.log` is nothing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Do you allow mod_rewrite in php.ini?

Comment: And then you must restart apache server 

Comment: I find out that mod_rewrite is not part of php but apache. What I did is: `sudo a2enmod rewrite` and `sudo service apache2 restart` but still does't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have an .htaccess in the document root folder, which is `/var/www` according to 000-default.conf.

But you don't allow .htaccess files in `/var/www`. You allow .htaccess files in `/var/www/html/movie`, again according to 000-default.conf.

To allow .htaccess files in `/var/www` or `/var/www/html`, you must say so, e.g.

```
<Directory /var/www>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

or

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

---

N.B. you don't need `AllowOverride All`, `AllowOverride FileInfo` is sufficient for using mod_rewrite, see [`AllowOverride`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride)